# When using a search field on a website, is there a way to open the search result in a new tab in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

For example, I go to http://en.wikipedia.org, I enter something into the search field, and I would like to see the search result in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the search box next to the address bar in Firefox to search on Wikipedia directly without explicitly having to go to the search box within a Wikipedia page. Within the Firefox search box, change the provider to Wikipedia

[image: Access Wikipedia Search Engine within Firefox]

For subsequent searches, click Alt+Enter after you enter a keyword within the search box instead of just Enter, to view results in a new tab.